# Upsert in persistent

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

How to do an atomic upsert in persistent?

Haven't managed to find a way to do an upsert, insert or update, operation using the persistent API. Something like update after insertBy seems to be the closest thing. But if I haven't understood something wrong, this won't be atomic and is thus prone to race conditions.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but here are some helpful facts that might get you closer- According to http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent, everything in a single runSqlite call is transactional (this is only sqlite, but the page implies to me that this will remain true if you flip out one database and put in another).  Also, upsert/merge seems to be a new addition to the SQL specs, and different databases seem to still be implementing the functionality in different ways.  There is also a section in the URL above about implementing custom database specific queries,  so perhaps you can use that.

Comment: +jamshidh's comment about transactions is vital here: since you're doing everything in a single transaction, multiple actions will be atomic, at least with all of the SQL backends.

Comment: So the special update API is there for those backends that don't support transactions?

Comment: Persistent2 seems to support upsert.

Answer (score 4):

Recent versions of `persistent` support [`upsert`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2.4/docs/Database-Persist-Class.html#v:upsert):

```
upsert :: (MonadIO m, PersistEntityBackend val ~ backend, PersistEntity val)     
       => val -> [Update val] -> ReaderT backend m (Entity val)
```